# Sass psuedo-selectors not working in Angular

Tags: angular, sass, frontend, primeng, angular7

[image]

I am trying to achieve the style shown in the image using Sass. I used `h1` tag with `:after` psuedo-selector to create this line. But `:after` is not working. I can achieve this style in React. I am using Angular7 with `angular-cli`.

```
<h1 class="login">Login</h1>

.login {
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    &:after {
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #faaf4a;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 40px;
    }
}
```

Kindly help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `content:"";` property.

```
<h1 class="login">Login</h1>

.login {
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    &:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #faaf4a;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 40px;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works!!! But why this property? I was able to achieve this without `content: ""` somewhere else...

Comment: For the `before` and `after` pseudo-elements to function properly, they must have a defined content property.

Answer (score 1):

add `content: ''`

```
.login {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  &:after {
    content: "";
      display: block;
      border-bottom: 4px solid #faaf4a;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 40px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`content: ""` is missing.

```css
.login {
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.login:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #faaf4a;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="login">Login</h1>
```